# In C# WPF, how do I set a label to be highlighted in a certain color AND add a mouse event handler programmatiacally?

Tags: c#, wpf

So I've set up a TreeView and inside it, I've placed Labels which I need to be highlighted permanently in either red or green on initialization. (Like in the picture) Does anyone know how to do this programmatically? I instantiate the labels like this

```
Label l = new Label() { Content = roomnumber };
```

ALSO!! I've been trying to link it to handle a mousedoubleclick event but doing this doesn't work either. any ideas?

```
Label l = new Label() { Content = roomnumber, MouseDoubleClick="Window_MouseDoubleClick" };
```

[image]

Comment: Did you set label's background?

Comment: WPF is a *lot* easier when you use MVVM and XAML. Doing it all in code is leaving a lot of it's power unused.

Comment: Yeah but the problem is I have to create a lot of the view programmatically :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `BackgroundProperty` of `Label` as like below.

```
//Green Colored Background
Label label = new Label() { Content = roomnumber, Background = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Green) };
//Red Colored Background
Label label = new Label() { Content = roomnumber, Background = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Red) };
```

Label also has a `MouseDoubleClick` event you can subscribe this.

```
label.MouseDoubleClick += label_MouseDoubleClick;
....
void label_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ////MessageBox.Show(((Label)sender).Content.ToString());
}
```